# how to define a function in the scope of a class but not as a member function

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, scope

i do not mean friend function. I guess there is not a way to achieve this in C++ like any other languages. Am I right?

The background:

I have a helper function for a class A. I know there are a couple of options here

(1) to declare it in the same namespace as class A is in

(2) put it as a static function of class A.

I was just thinking if it is possible to do the following which is kind of the combination of the above two. i.e.,

I want that function to be right under the scope of A but not as a member function of class A.

I hope this is clearer now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean something like static functions?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be in the scope of a class but not be a member? You need to clarify what you want, maybe even with pseudo-code with the intended use.

Comment: Why not put "free functions" inside a namespace instead of aa class? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What do you mean by within the scope of class A, but not a member of class A?

Comment: A is a class name is also a scope name. I basically want a function with in A but not as a member function. I know this question is a bit weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually do this is to declare a function in the .c++ file with 'static' qualifier. Please realize that is different from the normal use of c++ 'static' functions.

If you declare in 'bar.c++' (not 'bar.h++'):

```
static void foo() {}
```

...it is a function which is not 'visible' outside its object file. I.e. a local helper function.

So to be precise:

bar.h++;

```
class bar
{
  void f();
};
```

bar.c++;

```
#include "bar.h++"
static void foo() {}
void bar::f() { foo(); }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You mean a static member function.

```
class T
{
   static void lol();
};

void T::lol()
{
   /* ... */
}

int main()
{
   T::lol();
}
```

This isn't really "in the scope of the class" any more than a free function would be, because the only thing that can really mean is access to member variables, and access to member variables requires an instance.

But this is the closest to what you've asked.

Comment: He probably means that, even if the question explicitly requires this not to be the case: that is a static *member* function.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: ... which is what my answer says.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Please consider that the question doesn't make sense and that apparently OP hasn't an idea as to what he is doing.

Comment: @H2CO3: I know, I did not *downvote* or anything, just stated that the question is unclear (made a comment in the question) and that this is *probably* what he means, not what he asks for

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, yes, I realize, no problem with that. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like a static function?

```
class Foo
{
    void memberFunction();
    static void classFunction();
};

Foo foo;
foo.memberFunction(); // called as a member function
Foo::classFunction(); // called on the class, no object necessary
```

That's basically a function in the C++ "scope".  I'm not sure what you mean by scope though.  If you just mean namespace, then this is it.

Comment: Technically that is a static *member* function, probably what he wants, but it is unclear

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it as a static function - that is a function that is defined against the class but which does not require access to any particular instance of that class's member variables:

`static int foobar()...`

Which is then called with

`Foo::foobar();`

If you want to limit the scope of the function so it can ONLY be called from inside the class, you can make it `private` much like any other member function.

If you wish, there's nothing stopping you from creating a standard member function and just not accessing any member variables...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a nested class:

```
class A
{
    class X
    {
        void helper(A object)
        {
            std::cout << object.member;
        }
    };
    int member;
};
```

Here `helper` is a member function of class `Y`, not of class `A`. I am not sure how this helps you though.